# PCI Express slot configuration

Tags: pci

How can I arrange PCI Express slots for a specific order?
I use a PCI express VideoCapture Card and 8 camera on Ubuntu 18.04 and after reboot the order of the camera that is connected to slots changes.
I would like to keep the camera-slot order permanent.
Maybe I should write a rule but how can I write a rule for this purpose.

Comment: Assuming you mean `/dev/video0`, `/dev/video1` etc. by "slots": The order will always be random. Use `udev` rules to make symlinks, use the symlinks instead of the "raw" device names. Look at `/dev/disk/by-*` for an example how this works for disks.

Comment: Yes, I mean [/dev/video0] therefore I cannot find the idvendor, idproduct and serial number of camera that is mounted VideoCapture Card. [lspci -n] only shows me the idvendor of VideoCapture Card. How can I find the idvendor of camera ?
Thanks.

Comment: Try `lspci -nv`, the subsystem `vendor:id` is the only additional information for PCI cards I know of. There's no universal for "idproduct" or serial number in PCI cards. If you have a single PCI cards which 8 cameras attached (I've never heard about something like this), please edit question with the `lspci -nn` for the card so we can identify it, and use `udevadm` to inspect which information you get about each of the cameras.

Answer (score 0):

What's the name of the camera device you would like to assign to a specific card?
Running `sudo udevadm info -q all -a -n <device pathname>` should give you a listing of all the udev attributes you can use for creating udev rules for that particular device.

Comment: I cannot the connection info about camera that is mounted VideoCapture Card so how can i find device pathname?